Strategies to live in the present moment as an engaged academic?
Academia is full of challenges. Teaching, performing research, securing funding, (insert more tasks), ...
Many of these task require farsightedness and strong organizational skills. Oftentimes, one must plan months (or even years) ahead when it comes to large grants.
For me, this often results in constant thinking about academic schedule alignment - even in my free time. For example, I read a sign on the road or a newspaper headline and I think about a related topic at work with a deadline upcoming. For example, I see a headline about how good nutrition helps with cardiovascular disease and I think about an upcoming grant. I go to the supermarket and see a label that says "high fiber" and I automatically think about an ongoing study on fiber and obstipation.
This bothers more as I want to live more in the current moment and I want to reduce thinking about future job-related events. What organizational strategies and practical hints would you recommend to achieve this goal?

This seems like a question for a counsellor or even a psychiatrist.

The honest realizations that: my time is finite, my health can change in an instant and so can my whole world, my research while interesting to me and to a community of my peers is ultimately not world changing, my contributions to my University while important in the moment will be forgotten shortly after I leave, the fact that my children are aging faster than I can fully appreciate the developmental stages they are at. Everyone over-inflates the importance of what they do, and academics are probably the most guilty of it. So my advice - honest introspection.

I guess I'm just a nerd - I love seeing everyday stuff and wondering about it all. Perhaps not at the level of seeing grant proposals in everything - that sounds like work-related anxiety over funding. Perhaps rethinking as 'that is so cool', not 'I need the next grant'.

Dear Buffy, I slightly edited the question to clarify that I do not refer to psychological advice but rather techniques and strategies that may help to distinguish clearer between professional and private life.

Perhaps intrapersonal.stackexchange.com?

@R1NaNo As a developmental, I should push back against the idea of "stages" - it's a continuum

@AzorAhai-him- well maybe if I wasn't so disengaged with my family due to work stress I would have noticed it was a continuum!

@AzorAhai-him- - there is an _inter_personal stackexchange site, the closest to intrapersonal might be https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

@JonCuster Yes, that was the joke ;)

At some certain point, for example, if you have tenure (for what that's worth), it might be time to (try to) stop thinking about pleasing higher-ups, both within your department, and in the hierarchy of your university. Yes, if you're in a discipline that absolutely relies on external funding to be able to do anything, that's a rough spot. Sorry.
Nevertheless... :) ... if that's possible... :) ... think about The Ideal.
Improving collective human understanding, that kind of thing. Yes, quite a distance away from current public/political/whatever discourse. But, yes, try to stay focused on actual ... "facts". :)
One gauge is to think in terms of what you'll want to think about what you did in this moment... twenty years later. That kind of thing.
